# Is it allowed to emit a signal trough a pointer to an instance of another class?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

Minimal example:

```
class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:

    void
    TestSignal(int i) const;
};

class Bar : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

     Bar(Foo* foo) :
         mFoo{ foo }
     {}

    void
    TestEmit(int i) const
    {
        emit mFoo->TestSignal(i);
    }

private:

    Foo* mFoo;
};

void
Print(int i)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Usage:

```
Foo aFoo;
Bar aBar{ &aFoo };

connect(&aFoo, &Foo::TestSignal, &Print);

aBar.TestEmit(1337);
```

So I'm emitting the signal `Foo::TestSignal` from function `Bar::TestEmit` using a pointer to a `Foo` instance. This seems to work fine, but is it allowed ? (as in: reliable defined behavior).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code shown.  Do you have any particular reason for questioning the behaviour?

Comment: @G.M. Technically, signals are meant to be emitted from "inside" the class they belong to. So this might count as some kind of abuse that just happens to work but can't be depended on (?). Just trying to make sure - I don't find much about this kind of situation in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html :

> Signals are public access functions and can be emitted from anywhere,
> but we recommend to only emit them from the class that defines the
> signal and its subclasses

I understand it is technically allowed and reliable but not recommended in terms of code design.

You might also be interested to connect a signal to another as explained here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect